# How to exit or close an Javascript UWP app programmatically? (Windows 10)

Tags: javascript, windows-10, uwp, exit

I made a game and it needs it own exit button.

I was not able to use the [CoreApplication.Exit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.exit.aspx) static method here. There is no [CoreApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.aspx) class in [Windows.ApplicationModel.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.aspx) namespace in Javascript Applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CoreApplication.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.exit.aspx) is provided only for testing purposes. If you want to exit app you can close current window

```
    window.close();
```

---

Important note (from MSDN): If you use window.close, it appears as a crash to the user and is logged as a crash in the developer’s telemetry data on the Windows Store dashboard.

If you want to proactively "crash" app - you should use the [terminateApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770781.aspx) method.

Comment: There is a way to does not log as "crash" on dev center?

Comment: There is no other way. The idea is that user should not close application. He can just hide it and it would be suspended by the system and if needed it would be terminated also by the system.