# Programmatically exit from JavaScript based UWP application

Tags: uwp

How can I programmatically shutdown my Java Script based UWP application? If it was C# based one I would use [Application.Exit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit) but the class is not available to JavaScript applications. Is there a replacement for JavaScript?

Comment: [`window.close`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37851284/868014)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a choice, you can use the `window.close();` to close the application window.

In addition, you can also create a C# Windows Runtime Component project then call the C# code [CoreApplication.Exit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.exit#Windows_ApplicationModel_Core_CoreApplication_Exit) in your JS project to shut down the app. Starting with Windows 10, calling this method is no longer is treated as an app crash.

Firstly, in your solution, create a C# Windows Runtime Component project,

```
namespace ApplicationExitHelper
{
    public sealed class AppExitHelper
    {
        public void Exit()
        {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add this project to your JS project as a reference, then call the `exit()` method to exit your app.

```
function click(){
    var helper = new ApplicationExitHelper.AppExitHelper();
    helper.exit();
}
```

More details, you can see the topic [Walkthrough: Creating a Simple Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript)